# MVC Website - ServerGotRequest ServerBeginResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Been building a website in MVC 5, Framework 4.6.1. but I'm having a problem with the loading speeds.

After running fiddler (never used it), i found the delay is between ServerGotRequest and ServerBeginResponse, and this is running in localhost.

> Request Count:   1
>
> Bytes Sent:      545      (headers:545; body:0)
>
> Bytes Received:  6,263        (headers:428; body:5,835)
>
> ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
>   -------------- ClientConnected:   16:24:37.533
>
> ClientBeginRequest:   16:24:37.533
>
> GotRequestHeaders:    16:24:37.533
>
> ClientDoneRequest:    16:24:37.533
>
> Determine Gateway:    0ms
>
> DNS Lookup:       0ms
>
> TCP/IP Connect:   0ms
>
> HTTPS Handshake:  0ms
>
> ServerConnected:  16:24:37.535
>
> FiddlerBeginRequest:  16:24:37.535
>
> ServerGotRequest: 16:24:37.535
>
> ServerBeginResponse:  16:25:50.469
>
> GotResponseHeaders:   16:25:50.469
>
> ServerDoneResponse:   16:25:50.469
>
> ClientBeginResponse:  16:25:50.469
>
> ClientDoneResponse:   16:25:50.470
>
> Overall Elapsed:  0:01:12.937
>
> RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
>   -------------- text/html: 5,835 ~headers~: 428

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening :| this happens in Debug and in Release mode.

Any suggestion on where to look for the cause?

Comment: You should try [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It'll allow you to see what is taking up time a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a performance issue.

`ServerGotRequest` is telling you that the request from the client to the server has been received and the server is going to start processing your request.

`ServerBeginResponse` is telling you that the server has been processing your request and is now finished and is beginning to send the response stream back to the client.

What is happening in between is anybody's guess and you won't get a good answer from the group on this one since you haven't included code or even an explanation as what your application is trying to do.

There are some tools you can use to try to narrow it down.

You can enable tracing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx
You can implement glimpse: https://www.nuget.org/packages/glimpse

Or if you're using MVC (I assume you are) then simply comment out everything in your action and see what that does to performance then uncomment your code one or two lines at a time until you find the offender.

I'm guessing you discover a slow DB stored proc, calls to the database inside of a loop, multiple nested loops, or a combination of any of the three above.

Good luck!

Comment: Glimpse gives a good idea about the ones you mentioned. The only time when it didn't cut it was when I had a very heavy instantiation occurring during dependency injection :)