# IIS 7.5 WCF Application Initialization not working

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have some WCF services hosted in IIS 7.5, with application initialization module installed. Most of the services works perfectly fine expect one.

For that WCF I'm sure that application_start is called during the application pool initiate/recycle process refer to the log, however calling the .svc afterward took around 45s to respond, then the subsequent call is fast, sounds like the warmup is not happening on this WCF. I had no idea what are those 45s are doing.

As that WCF have numbers of .svc, first call to each of them also took around 40s to respond, even the first svc is already called, feels like they are trying to initiate individually.

One more question is that are there any differences between sending a warm up request to **/service** and **/service/service.svc**
? I've tried both of them but seem no differences. Cause I'm worried that if I have multiple .svc inside my WCF, do I have to send warmup request to all of them?

Took a look at the svclog and seems the issue is not related to Application Initialization

[image]

---

**Solved**
After research turn out the whole issue is not related to application initialization, but WCF's metadata exchange. Actually the image above already gave the hint of the issue. Thanks for your help Francesco B. !
http://www.synergex.com/blog/2015/06/25/why-is-that-first-wcf-operation-so-slow/

Comment: is there a way to introduce some logging inside your "slow" wcf? this way you could understand what it's doing during initialization. is there any database the service is connecting to?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there any way/tools that i can use up with? I tried to use fiddler to benchmark the performance and i found that the time were consumed between [ServerGotRequest] and [ServerBeginResponse]. My question is that what is being loaded when calling .svc? Their constructor are both empty though.

Comment: Your question seems very similar to another I've seen about MVC, have you checked its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35729605/5480409)? There are also suggestions about those tools you were referring to.
Anyway, can you share some code?

Comment: Btw, are there any properties in your WCF interface?

Comment: Thanks your reply again, the interface are quite simple, only with [ServiceContract] and some [ServiceKnownType]. Btw i've updated the question.

Comment: AFAIK if you just call "/service" the IIS will activate the default startup file, which can be index.html, index.php, service.msc etc depending on your configuration. So yes, if you have multiple svc you might have to warm them up individually. Can you post your service code, at least the most important parts?

Comment: Thanks Francesco, the issue was fixed, turn out its not related to application initialization. I've been going the wrong direction on this issue-_-

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Wcf metadata exchange, I updated my question, still curious that why application initialization is not doing that.

Comment: Actually this was an interesting question, when you have time you might wanna add an official "answer", it will certainly help someone else. Good job Nathan!